# Vue.js : $attrs is readonly, $listeners is readonly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, npm-link

I tried to build my own component library implementing Vuetify, by using vue-cli `vue create d-components`. My components are registered through an `install` function exported in my lib's main.ts file such as:

```js
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import DBtn from "./components/DBtn.vue";

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default {
  install(vue: VueConstructor): void {
    vue.component("d-btn", DBtn);
    ...
  }
}
```

And a component is defined as:

```html
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" elevation="0" small>
    ...
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class DBtn extends Vue {}
</script>
```

I added this library as a git submodule in my main Vue.js application (Which is also using Vuetify), ran `npm install` and `npm link` in the submodule's root folder, then ran `npm link d-components` in my main Application folder.

My application is importing & calling my library's install function via:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import DComponents from "d-components" // library's name

Vue.use(DComponents);
```

Everything seems OK so far.

But when I try to use my library's components, I get a bunch of errors:

`[Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.`

`[Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.`

It seems that this one comes from the fact that two instances of Vue are created in my application, I searched to see if all my Vue imports were the same, and I can only find `import Vue from 'vue'` in both my main application and my library.

Does anyone know how to check if I'm creating several instances of Vue ?

Comment: Consider moving Vue dependencies in package.json of a library submodule to "peerDependencies"

I have almost the same setup (Vue, vuetify, git submodule and even class components) and this worked for me without any "npm link" stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason is duplicate Vue instance, and I think there should be warning about that in your console.

The reason is your **npm link** done in submodule - which installs submobule package globally and all its dependencies including Vue. You can check node_modules directory of your globally installed submodule, you should see Vue there.

So you have first Vue in node_modules of your project and second Vue in node_modules of your component (globally installed).

The resolution is to use **npm link ../component** (not doing npm install in component dir) from your project directory either do **npm publish** for component and install it as a regular dependency for your project. That will not lead to install Vue into node_modules directory of your component.

Comment: I had no warning in the console other than the errors, but removing the node_modules folder of the linked library fixed the issue. I cannot use npm publish because my employer expressly forbid this. At least now I know what's happening and I know how to fix it, even if I can't publish my library (While removing the node_modules seems to work, it feels more like a hack than a proper solution). Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

In my case the duplicated instances were caused by some Vue plugins importing the Vue instance differently than set in my project. I managed to fix it by adding the following to my Webpack config:

```js
    externals: {
      // Stubs out `require('vue')` so it returns `global.Vue`
      vue: 'Vue',
    },
```

Hope it can help anyone struggling with the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you import the vue several times inside your code. So, you need to specify the path.

if you are using **vue 2.7** and **vite**, try to use this:

import path from 'path';

add in settings:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
     vue: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js'),
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$vuetify required package vuetify
```

Comment: What is the context of this?